# Testing - Intermittent error: 'Failed: The selector "#root0" did not match any elements'

Tags: testing, jasmine, karma-runner, angular

I'm working build an application on Angular2 beta version and when I'm running my test case, I randomly get the error:

> The selector "#root0" did not match any elements' error.

The test code:

```ts
@Component({
  template: '',
  directives: [GroupBox, GroupBoxHeader]
})
class TestComponent {
}

describe('group-box control', () => {

  it('should show the title', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb.overrideTemplate(TestComponent, '<group-box><group-box-header>Title Content</group-box-header></group-box>')
      .createAsync(TestComponent).then( (fixture) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(compiled).toContainText('Title Content');
    });
  }));

  it('should show the body', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb.overrideTemplate(TestComponent, '<group-box><group-box-header>Title Content</group-box-header>Body Content</group-box>')
      .createAsync(TestComponent).then( (fixture) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
        expect(compiled).toContainText('Body Content');
    });
  }));
});
```

Im using Karma with Jasmine, following the guidelines of https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed

The following repository reproduces the error: https://github.com/cangosta/ng2_testing_controls

StackTrace:

> 14 01 2016 11:40:32.073:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.19 server started at http://localhost:9876/
>   14 01 2016 11:40:32.078:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
>   14 01 2016 11:40:32.669:INFO [Chrome 47.0.2526 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#9hKZqsNbKFPfYWzIAAAA with id 50428936
>   Chrome 47.0.2526 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0) group-box control should show the body FAILED
>           Failed: The selector "#root0" did not match any elements
>           Error: The selector "#root0" did not match any elements
>               at new BaseException (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2.dev.js:8080:21)
>               at DomRenderer_.createRootHostView (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2.dev.js:15248:15)
>               at AppViewManager_.createRootHostView (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2.dev.js:11265:52)
>               at C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2.dev.js:14531:46
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>               at zoneBoundFn (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1494:11)
>               at C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:243:5
>               at microtask (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2557:15)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>               at zoneBoundFn (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>               at lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1305:9)
>           Failed: Cannot read property 'hostView' of undefined
>           TypeError: Cannot read property 'hostView' of undefined
>               at new ComponentFixture_ (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2047:97)
>               at C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2145:16
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>               at zoneBoundFn (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1494:11)
>               at C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:243:5
>               at microtask (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2557:15)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>               at zoneBoundFn (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>               at lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1305:9)
>           Failed: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined
>           TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined
>               at C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/test/infrastructure/controls/group-box.test.js:52:20
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>               at zoneBoundFn (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$tryCatch (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1511:16)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1523:17)
>               at lib$es6$promise$$internal$$publish (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1494:11)
>               at C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:243:5
>               at microtask (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2557:15)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:138:17)
>               at Zone.run (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/testing.dev.js:2544:30)
>               at zoneBoundFn (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:111:19)
>               at lib$es6$promise$asap$$flush (C:/Projectos/Fontes/Stratus-HTML/build/assets/js/angular2-polyfills.js:1305:9)
>   Chrome 47.0.2526 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0): Executed 59 of 60 (1 FAILED) (skipped 1) (0.519 secs / 0.51 secs)
>   [11:40:33] 'test' errored after 2.01 s
>   [11:40:33] Error: 1
>       at formatError (C:\Users\LSANTOS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:169:10)
>       at Gulp. (C:\Users\LSANTOS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\bin\gulp.js:195:15)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at Gulp.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at Gulp.Orchestrator._emitTaskDone (C:\Projectos\Fontes\Stratus-HTML\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:264:8)
>       at C:\Projectos\Fontes\Stratus-HTML\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:275:23
>       at finish (C:\Projectos\Fontes\Stratus-HTML\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
>       at cb (C:\Projectos\Fontes\Stratus-HTML\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:29:3)
>       at removeAllListeners (C:\Projectos\Fontes\Stratus-HTML\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:333:7)
>       at Server. (C:\Projectos\Fontes\Stratus-HTML\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:344:9)
>       at Server.g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
>       at Server.emit (events.js:166:7)
>       at emitCloseNT (net.js:1518:8)
>       at doNTCallback1 (node.js:418:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:340:17)

Comment: I'll try it. I'm not using TS, I'm using ES6+Traceur. I've created a repo where you can easily reproduce the error: https://github.com/cangosta/ng2_testing_controls

Comment: Gunter, I've updated the repository with a simplified version

Comment: There's a [bug with TestComponentBuilder](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5662) with templateUrl.  Temporary fix for it is to use `.overrideTemplate(TestComponent, `<div></div>`)` as you're doiing. BUT, you're overriding TestComponent and NOT GroupBox component which also has `templateUrl: './group-box.html'`... I beleive this is what's causing the error, but unfortunately I don't know how to fix it - I only tested isolated components...

Comment: Sasxa, removing the templateUrl from the group-box component does solve the problem, but it is not a solution, since I have huge component template throughout my application. It seems to me that I will have to wait for the angular team to fix this bug...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - testing component with two "it" creates 'selector "#root0" did not match any elements error'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142641/angular2-testing-component-with-two-it-creates-selector-root0-did-not-ma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in Angular 2.0.0-beta.3

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6483#issuecomment-179557485 for more details

> Basically, what I had to do:
>
> - Manually add typings for jasmine with tsd install jasmine -so and add `///<reference...` in the test files;
> - Add this in my imports:

```ts
import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';

import {
  TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';
```

> Add this before my Component tests:

```ts
  setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```