# Angular2 - testing component with two "it" creates 'selector "#root0" did not match any elements error'

Tags: unit-testing, angular

I am trying to create a simple component test, when I createAsync an element twice I get The selector "#root0" did not match any elements error. I assume it creates it the second time with #root1 but looks for #root0

```
it('should render',
    inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
      tcb.createAsync(TestComponent)
        .then((componentFixture) => {
          componentFixture.detectChanges();
          expect(true).toBeTruthy();      
          componentFixture.destroy();
        }).catch((e) =>{
          console.log(e);
        });
    })
);

it('should render',
    inject([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
      tcb.createAsync(TestComponent)
        .then((componentFixture) => {
          componentFixture.detectChanges();
          expect(true).toBeTruthy();      
          componentFixture.destroy();
        }).catch((e) =>{
          console.log(e);
        });
    })
);
```

If I run just one "it" test it works fine. the second one fails... I tried it with and without the componentFixture.destroy(); but no success...
To be clear - the tests passes, but the error shows up in the console.

Here is the complete error log:

> LOG: BaseException{message: 'The selector "#root0" did not match any elements', stack: 'Error: The selector "#root0" did not match any elements
>       at new BaseException (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js?914563a3aa3b4999ed51fe88c1b6233d2f09e880:7070:21)
>       at DomRenderer.selectRootElement (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js?914563a3aa3b4999ed51fe88c1b6233d2f09e880:13643:15)
>       at HostViewFactory.viewFactory_HostTestComponent0 [as viewFactory] (viewFactory_HostTestComponent:72:18)
>       at AppViewManager_.createRootHostView (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js?914563a3aa3b4999ed51fe88c1b6233d2f09e880:9172:34)
>       at http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js?914563a3aa3b4999ed51fe88c1b6233d2f09e880:12189:46
>       at M (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:8769)
>       at H (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:8401)
>       at R.when (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:12075)
>       at b.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:11111)
>       at t._drain (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:3029)
>       at drain (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:2683)
>       at MutationObserver.e (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js?064ab212cfd9e125474ae3bbb600c366b31e79cb:4:4604)
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js?2a193e6e9bdd25760b711f1ce03caeac530e48c1:138:17)
>       at MutationObserver.zoneBoundFn (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js?2a1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6483 (dup of https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5662) when `templateUrl` is used in components.

**Update**

This is fixed in Angular 2.0.0-beta.3

See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6483#issuecomment-179557485 for more details

> Basically, what I had to do:
>
> - Manually add typings for jasmine with tsd install jasmine -so and add `///<reference...` in the test files;
> - Add this in my imports:

```ts
import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';

import {
  TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
  TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';
```

> Add this before my Component tests:

```ts
  setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
```

Answer (score 0):

An update to the update:
Beta.3 did fix the problem as Günter Zöchbauer mentioned, we can now use injectAsync that didn't work before.
Also I suggest to use this:

```
import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {getTestInjector} from 'angular2/testing';
import {TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';

if (getTestInjector().platformProviders.length === 0 || getTestInjector().applicationProviders.length === 0) {
  setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);
}
```

otherwise you will get an error when loading your BaseTestProviders the second time.